# How can I assign values to next n rows in SQL based on the value of a previous row?

Tags: sql

Please help,
I need to be able to determine if the next seven rows fall within 7 days of a row's date. How to do this in Sql or excel?
I am at a loss.

Comment: previous row is `lag` analytic function

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
create table #Temp 
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    InsertedDate datetime,
    Data_XYZ varchar(50)
)

truncate table #Temp

insert into #Temp 
values
('1/1/2020','A'),
('1/2/2020','B'),
('1/3/2020','C'),
('1/4/2020','D'),
('1/5/2020','E'),
('1/8/2020','F'),
('1/10/2020','G'),
('1/11/2020','H'),
('1/17/2020','I'),
('1/20/2020','J'),
('1/25/2020','K'),
('1/26/2020','L'),
('1/26/2020','M'),
('1/31/2020','N')

declare @InsertedDate datetime; set @InsertedDate='1/5/2020';

select top 7 * 
from #Temp 
where ID > (select ID from #Temp where InsertedDate = @InsertedDate)
  and InsertedDate between @InsertedDate and DATEADD(dd, 7, @InsertedDate)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Also: if you post such a large portion of code, please also **explain** what you're doing and why you believe this will help solve the OP's problem/question ... don't just dump a huge pile of code on us, without any explanation ....

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use `lead()`.  You haven't provided a database tag -- or even defined what you mean by "7 days".

But the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(date, 7) over (order by date) <= date + interval '7 day'
             then 'within'
             else 'without'
        end) 
from t;
```